# How to solve Could not resolve dependency on gitlab

Tags: dependencies, gitlab, next.js, tslint

I am facing this issue with GitLab CI jobs. Everything is working fine locally but when I execute `npm install` on GitLab, I'm getting this error

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.5.0-rc2 (71c90c86)
  on docker-auto-scale z3WU8uu-
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:38
Using Docker executor with image node:latest ...
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:ca36fba5ad66b0f8fce2b97a6f0aa53267395388ada988534d848638312ccb68 for node:latest with digest node@sha256:bf60a164bc588967ce6e3342c9d6508bf9ad2e7e2a1c237315596eab3e13428b ...
Preparing environment
00:03
Running on runner-z3wu8uu--project-17807115-concurrent-0 via runner-z3wu8uu--srm-1603491340-e6ca0bf8...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/DreamStartLabs/save/save-plus-web/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 54f78e46 as feat-donors-infinite-scroll...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:06
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: save-plus-web@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: tslint@6.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!   dev tslint@"^6.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer tslint@"^5.11.0" from tslint-config-airbnb@5.11.2
npm ERR! node_modules/tslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!   dev tslint-config-airbnb@"^5.11.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-23T22_17_10_389Z-debug.log
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I tried to uninstall tslint-config-airbnb@5.11.2 and tslint@6.1.3, then reinstall them but nothing is changing

Comment: Check the user with which you are executing runner has permission to npm

Comment: Which version of npm are you using? If it is 7.0.4 you should update, because it has a bug: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by uninstalling this `tslint` package; In fact, because the package is not maintained anymore as said here https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint

The tslint version wasn't compatible with the `tslint-config-airbnb` which is also deprecated https://github.com/progre/tslint-config-airbnb

`TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. Could be related to latest node (v15) and npm (v7) versions.

Try using `node:lts` or `node:lts-alpine` images.

Comment: :( yes it is related ... a workaround would be  `npm i --force --legacy-peer-deps`